# How to use NULL character with NSString?

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding, nsstring

In PHP, I can call `base64_encode("\x00". $username. "\x00". $password)` and the `"\x00"` represents a NULL character.

Now, in Objective-C, I have a function that converts NSData to [base64 encoded NSString](http://www.cocoadev.com/BaseSixtyFour) created by DaveDribin.

How do I create data from a string that has NULL characters?

This doesn't seem to work...

```
NSData * authCode = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@%c%@", '\0', self.username, '\0', self.password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: please describe "doesn't work"

Comment: Why does your string include NUL characters? This sounds suspiciously like something that should be an NSData to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
char bytes[] = "\0username\0password";
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Output:

```
2010-01-22 09:15:22.546 app[6443] <00757365 726e616d 65007061 7373776f 726400>
```

Or from `NSString`:

```
char bytes[] = "\0username\0password";
NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData * data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can see the null bytes at the beginning, in between username/password and at the end - because the `char[]` is null terminated.

Comment: You're initializing the string twice (with `[NSString string]` and with `initWithBytes:length:`). Also, you may need to use `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` to actually build.

Comment: Corrected the bad initialization of combining +string with -init, because as the accepted answer, people are going to copy this code and the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct.  NSString just doesn't handle `NULL` bytes well.  I can't find any documentation about it, but NSString will silently ignore `%c` format specifiers with an argument of `0` (and on that note, the character constant `'\0'` expands to the integer `0`; that is correct).  It can, however, handle `\0` directly embedded into an NSString literal.

See this code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *stringByChars = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%c%c%c%c-",0,0,0,0];
    NSString *stringByEscapes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-\0\0\0\0-"];
    NSLog(@"  stringByChars: \"%@\"", stringByChars);
    NSLog(@"            len: %d", [stringByChars length]);
    NSLog(@"           data: %@", [stringByChars dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSLog(@"stringByEscapes: \"%@\"", stringByEscapes);
    NSLog(@"            len: %d", [stringByEscapes length]);
    NSLog(@"           data: %@", [stringByEscapes dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

returns:

```
  stringByChars: "--"
            len: 2
           data: <2d2d>
stringByEscapes: "-
            len: 6
           data: <2d000000 002d>
```

(Note that since the `stringByEscapes` actually contains the `NULL` bytes, it terminates the NSLog string early).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why this works, but instead of using @"%c" as the format string with '\0', try using @"%@" as the format string with @"\0"

Answer (score 0):

[stefanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111766/how-to-use-null-character-with-nsstring/2113386#2113386) looks like a right option. Turns out I was passing in wrong info to make it look like \0 wasn't working

This was ok:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\0user\0pass"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this (tested and working - taken from: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/174917-nul-characters-in-nsstring-cause-unexpected-results.html)

```
NSString* s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof (buffer)
      encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF16LE)]; // @"A[NUL]end" (*)
NSLog(@"s1 = %@", s1);
NSString* s2 = @"CD";
NSLog(@"s2 = %@", s2) ;
NSString* sC = [s1 stringByAppendingString:s2];
NSLog(@"sC = %@", sC);
NSLog(@"length of s1:%i", [s1 length]);
NSLog(@"length of s2:%i", [s2 length]);
NSLog(@"length of sC:%i", [sC length]);
[s1 release];
```