# asyncSocket writeData crashes with different NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, byte, nsdata

If I use this  to set up NSData then the writeData method crashes.

```
   NSString *test = @"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog\r\n";
   NSData *data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   [asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:10 tag:4];
```

However if I use this one then it works... but I need the NSString so I can enter a formatted string to send...

```
 char bytes[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog\r\n";
 NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

 [asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:10 tag:4];
```

So what did I do wrong?

Comment: theoretically, the both of the above NSData should have the exact same bits in them...  do and NSLog on the NSData in both cases and compare the log output...

Comment: @amattn, no, they do not have the same bits - char[] is null terminated so the string ends 0d0a00 whereas the first version just ends 0d0a.

Comment: the other issue then is that you have a memory leak with the second version.  since it's an asyncSocket, I wonder if the asyncSocket isn't holding on to the data in the first example?

Comment: I am too new to iPhone ObjC to understand what is going on.  Maybe it would be better for me to write something using the BSD connection library?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSString and the NSDate were not setup with alloc and init so they were gone when they got to the write data. I changed the NSDate to alloc and init and all works well now.  These idea came from the several people that answered this.  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The latter is null terminated, the former is not. This is probably the issue.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, I tried adding the null on with the NSString format using %c and 0 but it didnt work.  How do I add on the null?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111766/how-to-use-null-character-with-nsstring

Comment: thanks for the link, I now have the null on the end and both ways of creating the data outputs the same in the log.  But it still crashes.  The 2nd data above is created with alloc whereas the 1st one come from NSString.  Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: What exactly is your crash - the 1st is autoreleased whereas the second is retained, and yes that could be another problem, but the crash should tell you the details.

Comment: Its crashing in the AysyncSocket clas - doSendBytes

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: while (!done && !error && [self canAcceptBytes])
 {
  // Figure out what to write
  NSUInteger bytesRemaining = [theCurrentWrite->buffer length] - theCurrentWrite->bytesDone;

Comment: wonder if I should forget the GCDAsyncSocket and go with the old BSD stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I know its bit late but I thought it would be good to know why this works - When you call writeData method with your data buffer, the asyncsocket code creates a new object by sublassing NSObject - AsyncWritePacket using the data passed down.  It then uses retain and takes ownership of the data buffer you are passing hence why you dont want to release it.

```
@implementation AsyncWritePacket
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)d timeout:(NSTimeInterval)t tag:(long)i
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        buffer = [d retain];
        timeout = t;
        tag = i;
        bytesDone = 0;
    }
    return self;

@end
```