# What does \0 stand for?

Tags: objective-c, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the \0 symbol mean in a C string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711449/what-does-the-0-symbol-mean-in-a-c-string)

I am new at iPhone Development. I want to know, what does `'\0'` means in **C**, and what is the equivalent for that in **objective c.**

Comment: `\O` or `\0`  `O` or `Zero`? `\0` means null ASCII value is `0`

Comment: 6 million results on google, with just `\0`

Answer (score 29):

The null character `'\0'` (also `null terminator`), abbreviated `NUL`, is a control character with the value `zero`. Its the same in **C** and **objective C**

The character has much more significance in C and it serves as a reserved character used to signify the end of a `string`,often called a [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

The length of a [C string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string) (an array containing the characters and terminated with a `'\0'` character) is found by searching for the **(first) NUL byte**.

Answer (score 11):

In C, `\0` denotes a character with value zero. The following are identical:

```
char a = 0;
char b = '\0';
```

The utility of this escape sequence is greater inside string literals, which are arrays of characters:

```
char arr[] = "abc\0def\0ghi\0";
```

(Note that this array has *two* zero characters at the end, since string literals include a hidden, implicit terminal zero.)

Answer (score 6):

The `'\0'` inside character literals and string literals stands for the character with the code zero. The meaning in C and in Objective C is identical.

To illustrate, you can use `\0` in an array initializer to construct an array equivalent to a null-terminated string:

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
char str2[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

In general, you can use `\ooo` to represent an ASCII character in *octal* notation, where `o`s stand for up to three octal digits.

Comment: ... or `'\xXY'` for hexadecimal. Not sure how that is a "generalization" of `'\0'` though, they're different concepts.

Comment: @unwind `\0` is zero in octal notation. [Microsoft's page on escape characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does not have a specific entry on `\0`, "bundling" it together with other octal character literals.

Comment: @unwind: note also that `0` is an *octal* integer constant, and is a special case of the fact that in general one can write `0[0-7]*` for an octal integer constant. Not that it makes any difference whether `0` is formally defined to be an octal vs decimal constant, but as it happens the grammar classifies it as octal, as it does the `\0` escape :-)

Answer (score 6):

To the C language, `'\0'` means exactly the same thing as the integer constant `0` (same value zero, same type `int`).

To someone reading the code, writing `'\0'` suggests that you're planning to use this particular zero as a character.

Answer (score 3):

`\0` is zero character. In `C` it is mostly used to indicate the termination of a character string. Of course it is a regular character and may be used as such but this is rarely the case.

The simpler versions of the built-in string manipulation functions in `C` require that your string is null-terminated(or ends with `\0`).

Comment: to add it in a string (in Objective C) what should i do...

Comment: @SaurabhJadhav it seems the usage in `Objective-C` is similar to the one in `C`. Also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111766/how-to-use-null-character-with-nsstring)

Comment: i have looked at the link you gave it to me but i want it another way for eg. in objective c NSString * str = @"A\0B\0C";  so i want the output as followed A B C..ie i want escape that \0 from the string..

Comment: If you want such output, you need to replace `'\0'` with a space character. I believe you can do this using a single iteration(I am not sure if there is a built-in function in `Objective-C` to do that)

Answer (score 0):

In C `\0` is a character literal constant store into an `int` data type that represent the character with value of 0.

Since Objective-C is a strict superset of C this constant is retained.

Comment: C does not specify the number of bits in a `char`.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Fixing the anwer

Comment: @KerrekSB What about `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>`? But how's that relevant? Did I miss an edit to this answer?

Comment: CHAR_BIT tells you what that particular compiler implements. The C standard doesn't say much about what this value is - it could be 8, 9, 11 or 32 in CHAR_BIT.

Answer (score -4):

It means '\0' is a `NULL` character in C, don't know about `Objective-C` but its probably the same.

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer, `\0` is a character.

Comment: @KerrekSB `NULL` can be defined as simply `0` (explicitly allowed by C99), in which case there won't be difference from `'\0'`.

Comment: One-l nul terminates a string, two-l null stands for no thing.